# Cylinder rotating without slipping on an accelerating slab

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, forces

I am very confused by the following problem asked in my first year physics class:

[image]

Please let me know if you can assist in any way! I've spent hours and hours on this question and gained absolutely nothing. Everything I do seems to lead to a contradiction one way or another.

There are other resources online I've found that mention this question, but I can't tease out a good solution from these:
[Force on a solid cylinder that is rolling on an accelerating block](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/151579/force-on-a-solid-cylinder-that-is-rolling-on-an-accelerating-block)
https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/a-rolling-disc-on-a-slab.594918/

Thank you!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is a homework question I won't give you a full solution, only point you in the right direction.

On the lower block acts a second force, $F_F$, a friction force that causes torque and the angular acceleration $\alpha$ of the cylinder:

$$F_F R=-I\alpha$$

Where $I$ is the moment of inertia of the cylinder and $R$ its radius. It carries a minus sign because it points in the opposite direction of $F$.

So the net force acting on the block is:

$$F_{net}=F-F_F$$

Now also note that for rolling without slipping, with $a$ the acceleration of the block, then:

$$a=\alpha R$$

To determine $a$ and $\alpha$ use the equations above to set up:

$$F_{net}=ma$$

Comment: For the cylinder, would we not have

F(net) = f = m*ac -> ac = f / m

where f is the static friction and ac is the acceleration of the cylinder?

But since it rolls without slipping we know that

alpha*R = ac

and

T = R*f = I*alpha = 1/2 * m * R^2 * alpha -> alpha = ac / R = 2f/(m*R)

giving us both

ac = f / m and ac = 2f / m,

a contradiction!

(Apologies, I don't know how to make equations look nice.)

Comment: We're only concerned with $a_{block}$. That's what the question is about. Find $\alpha$ from the relevant formula.

Comment: Put another way, to find $a$ you only need to look at the forces that act on $m$.

Comment: Thank you so much Gert! I have posted my solution here: http://imgur.com/a/Ld1QT. I am still confused, however, why the cylinder has a force in the positive horizontal direction, yet does not accelerate in that direction. Is that not a violation of Newton's Second Law?

Comment: The cylinder *does* accelerate, by: $a_c=a-\alpha R$, in the stationary reference frame. Thanks!